# What framwework to use for SOAP if using Websphere Application Server

Tags: web-services, websphere, cxf, apache-axis

I have been going over the list of frameworks available for SOAP.  My application is Spring MVC pattern and its deployed on Websphere servers.  Do I still need to use framworks like Axis 2 or CXF?  Can I just Use spring?

Comment: WebSphere Application Server provides JAX-WS compliant web service engine, so you don't need to pack Axis or CXF inside your application to be able to use web services.

Answer (score 1):

As Gas pointed out WebSphere provides support for JAX-WS (i.e. Java API for XML Web Services) since WAS 7.0. Additionally IBM provided [Feature Pack for Web Services for WebSphere Application Server V6.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264563) that supported JAX-WS.

Even earlier versions of WAS supported JAX-RPC (since J2EE 1.4) but I do not recommend JAX-RPC approach because it was cumbersome and I don't think anyone is still using it. It is in fact deprecated since JEE 6.

So you do not need to use external libraries. Using standard JAX-WS implementation from WebSphere gives you possibility to easily configure services from administration console. This is especially nice when you integrate with other IBM WebSphere products or use some IBM standards like LTPA tokens. However, this implementation does not integrate with Spring.

You also might use external libraries, like Axis 2, Apache CXF or Metro. These also have some advantages. For instance Apache CXF integrates really nice with Spring and supports many standards. Spring WS is on the other hand minimalistic.

However, with these libraries you must expect some problems with class conflicts as they require often different versions of libraries than WebSphere provides. This might require you to change default classloading policy or other tweaks. It is possible to deal with but it is not for free.